# Tutorial: Controlling simulated robot in Webots with ROS, using joystick

Tags: tutorial, ros-electric, ros-fuerte, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Tutorial: Controlling simulated robot in Webots with ROS, using joystick**  
Tested with: 
Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)
ROS Fuerte, should be compatible with Electric and Diamond

Hi all,

The sample ROS controller for Webots provided at: 
http://www.ros.org/wiki/webots 
no longer works, because it requires the deprecated 'joy' node.

I've used this work by Andreas Breitenmoser & Olivier Michel to create a new Webots stack:  
http://kaist-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kaist_webots/ 
The structure, compilation and launch method have been modified to suit the current ROS standard. 
Users need to have an existing installation of Webots, but the simulation can be started from a single ROS launch file.

It has been tested with ROS Fuerte, and a complete walk-through guide follows below. 
This tutorial will be posted on the Wiki shortly.

~ David.

**
Edit: has now been posted on the wiki  [http://www.ros.org/wiki/kaist_webots](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kaist_webots) **

.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44742/tutorial:-controlling-simulated-robot-in-webots-with-ros,-using-joystick/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-28**:
Very cool. Is this a question? If not, Planet ROS might be a better place to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @joq it's on the wiki now.

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0